# How to get property name from the sender object of an INotifyPropertyChanged PropertyChanged event

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, dependencyobject, inotifycollectionchanged

I have a base DependencyObject class where I have a method that takes an object, gets the properties, and for each property that is a type that implements INotifyPropertyChanged, I add a new PropertyChangedEventHandler. Now in the handler method, it gets the parameters of an object "sender" and the PropertyChangedEventArgs "e". My question is, does anyone know how to dynamically get the property name if sender is a property of a type that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
public class BaseDependencyObject : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public BaseDependencyObject()
    {

    }

    protected void SetValues(Object thisObject, Object entity)
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(entity, null);
                var valueIsEntity = value is System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.Entity;
                var thisObjectsProperty = thisObject.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);

                if (thisObjectsProperty != null && value != null)
                {
                    if (valueIsEntity)
                    {
                        if (thisObjectsProperty.PropertyType.GetInterface("INotifyPropertyChanged", true) != null)
                        {
                            var propertyInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(thisObjectsProperty.PropertyType);

                            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)propertyInstance).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Object_PropertyChanged);
                        }

                        SetValues(thisObjectsProperty, value);
                    }

                    else if (thisObjectsProperty.PropertyType.GetInterface("ICollection", true) != null
                        && thisObjectsProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        Type genericType = thisObjectsProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                        var observableCollection = Activator.CreateInstance(thisObjectsProperty.PropertyType) as IList;

                        if (observableCollection is INotifyCollectionChanged)
                            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)observableCollection).CollectionChanged += this.Object_CollectionChanged;

                        if (observableCollection is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)observableCollection).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Object_PropertyChanged);

                        foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)value)
                        {
                            var newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);

                            if (newItem != null)
                            {
                                SetValues(newItem, item);
                                observableCollection.Add(newItem);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        thisObjectsProperty.SetValue(thisObject, value, null);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected void Object_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    if (item is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                    {
                        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Object_PropertyChanged);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    if (item is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                    {
                        ((INotifyPropertyChanged)item).PropertyChanged -= this.Object_PropertyChanged;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    protected void Object_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    }
}
```

The SetValues method's first param is the DependencyObject type that will be used in the view model. The second param is the entity that is being returned from the DomainService's Context.LoadOperation.

What my issue boils down to is when the INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged fires I'm needing to be able to raise the PropertyChanged event with the collection's property name. So if anyone has any advise I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Figured out how to get the properties name that is firing the event. Here is an edited version of my PropertyChangedEventHandler.

```
protected void Object_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType == sender.GetType()).ToArray();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged(property.Name);
        }

        //this.NotifyPropertyChanged(e.PropertyName);
    }
```

Basically this does what I was looking for, but aparentyly I am still not doing something right. The UIElement is still not updating when the ObservableCollection that is a property of another type is being added to.

Here is an example of my DependencyObjects and ViewModel:

```
public class LOB : DependencyObject
{
    public Int32 ID
    {
        get { return (Int32)GetValue(IDProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IDProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IDProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ID", typeof(Int32), typeof(LOB), null);

    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Group>)GetValue(GroupsProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GroupsProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Groups");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Groups", typeof(ObservableCollection<Group>), typeof(LOB), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnGroupsPropertyChanged));

    static void OnGroupsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.NewValue).CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(((LOB)obj).Object_CollectionChanged);
            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)e.NewValue).PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(((LOB)obj).Object_PropertyChanged);
        }
        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue).CollectionChanged -= ((LOB)obj).Object_CollectionChanged;
            ((INotifyPropertyChanged)e.OldValue).PropertyChanged -= ((LOB)obj).Object_PropertyChanged;
        }
    }

}

public class Group : DependencyObject
{
    public Int32 ID
    {
        get { return (Int32)GetValue(IDProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IDProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IDProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ID", typeof(Int32), typeof(Group), null);

    public String GroupName
    {
        get { return (String)GetValue(GroupNameProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(GroupNameProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("GroupName");
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GroupNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("GroupName", typeof(String), typeof(Group), null);

}

public class MyViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LobCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LobCollection",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<LOB>),
            typeof(MyViewModel),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, LobCollectionPropertyChanged));

    public ObservableCollection<LOB> LobCollection
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<MainBusinessLine>)GetValue(LobCollectionPropertyChanged); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MainBusinessLineCollectionProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("LobCollection");
        }
    }

    static void LobCollectionPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = obj as MyViewModel;

        if (viewModel == null)
            return;

        if (e.OldValue != null)
        {
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.OldValue).CollectionChanged -= viewModel.LobCollection_Changed;
        }

        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            ((INotifyCollectionChanged)e.NewValue).CollectionChanged += viewModel.LobCollection_Changed;
        }

    }

    void LobCollection_Changed(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("LobCollection");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me be sure I understand your question properly: You've got this class: "public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged { INotifyCollectionChanged collection; }", and when the CollectionChanged event fires, you want the PropertyChanged event to fire on the owning class. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Plus I edited my original post to show an updated version which does some what that. Granted it's not the greatest solution, but for the moment I just want to be able to add to an observable collection within another observable collection.

Comment: What you're doing in your LOB and Group classes makes the most sense to me. Handling it in the base class is certainly possible, but having a mix of DependancyProperty and INotifyPropertyChanged does make it harder. Also, note that technically speaking, I think you're not following the contract of INotifyPropertyChanged: the property's value hasn't changed, the collection inside of it has. The standard way to do this would be to let the CollectionChanged event fire, and leave it at that.

Comment: First I think I should add now that when I made some changes to the xaml, my UIElement updated and showed the new items correctly. So that brought up the question of, "Have I over engineered it now by using the DependencyProperty and INotifyPropertyChanged???" And by your statement above I'm guessing I did. So, what do you think is better practice, DP's or INotify's?  And you also said to leave it with the CollectionChanged event. Do I not need to raise a PropertyChanged event for that collection property?  And thank you David for responding. My head was getting sore from hitting the wall.

Comment: My general philosophy on DependancyObject & INotifyPropertyChanged is to use one or the other. If it is necessary to use both on the same class, I wouldn't fire a PropertyChanged event for a DependancyProperty: Whatever you're binding to that property has already received change notification from the DP, the PropertyChanged is unnecessary.

Comment: In general, well-written WPF components should see that they are bound to a INotifyCollectionChanged, and not require the PropertyChanged event to know when to re-read the list. In fact, some components are smart enough that if you fire a PropertyChanged event without actually changing the list object held by the property, they won't re-read the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our conversation above, this is rather moot, but I thought about how I'd implement a base class that fired PropertyChanged events when a collection changed in a property that was defined by the subclass. As I said, it's a bit non-standard, but here's how I'd do it.

```
class FancyCollectionAndPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Dictionary<ICollectionChanged, String> collectionNameLookup = new Dictionary<ICollectionChanged, String>();

    protected FancyCollectionAndPropertyChangedBase()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += MyPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void MyPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.collectionNameLookup.ContainsValue(e.PropertyName)
        {
            KeyValuePair<INotifyCollectionChanged, String> oldValue = this.collectionNameLookup.First(kvp => kvp.Value == e.Name);
            oldValue.Key -= MyCollectionChanged;
            this.collecitonNameLookup.Remove(oldValue.Key);

            INotifyCollectionChanged collection = this.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName, BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(this, null);
            collection.CollectionChanged += MyCollectionChanged;
            this.collectionNameLookup.Add(collection, e.Name);
        }
        else if(typeof(INotifyCollectionChanged).IsAssignableFrom(this.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName,  BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).PropertyType))
        {
            // Note: I may have gotten the IsAssignableFrom statement, above, backwards. 
            INotifyCollectionChanged collection = this.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName, BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).GetValue(this, null);
            collection.CollectionChanged += MyCollectionChanged;
            this.collectionNameLookup.Add(collection, e.Name);
        }
    }

    private void MyCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(this.collectionNameLookup[sender];
    }
}
```

Comment: David, I just wanted to let you know I used the basis of your code that you posted above and implemented it into my Base class. Everything is working smoothly now. I definitely appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this. I'll mark this as the answer since a mixture of everything turned out to be the trick. Also, I removed the inheritance from DependencyObject and only implemented the INotify interfaces. If in the future, someone needs to see the finished code I will be glad to post it. Thanks again.